# ssh-agent and ssh-add

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent, ssh-keys

Does anyone know how to make it so that I don't have to add my keys manually using ssh-add?  Every time I log into my Ubuntu server box, I have to start the ssh-agent and then use ssh-add before my keys are available.  Have I done something to mess up the default behavior of ssh?  Let me know if there's information I can provide that would help answering this question.

Comment: also related: http://superuser.com/a/1152861/670755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this thread on askubuntu.com: [Why wont ssh agent save my unencrypted key for later use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36255/why-wont-ssh-agent-save-my-unencrypted-key-for-later-use)

It gives the parameters you need to use in bash to wake up `ssh-agent` on each login.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  For future internet readers, if you're like me, you have a bunch of leftover ssh-agent processes from your previous attempts.  "sudo killall ssh-agent" will kill all of them.