# Save identities added by ssh-add so they persist

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I recently setup `openssh` so I could use it with `git`.

### In the process of setting it up (as per [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)) I ran the commands:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/<name of key>
```

Some time later, after I logged out and back in I tried to use `git push` I got an error. The solution to this error was running those same commands again.

### Please tell me how I can

- Keep the `ssh-agent` running so I don't have to start a new one
- Remember the keys I've added so I don't have to add them everytime

Just to clarify, I use zsh so certain bash features won't work in my .zshrc.

Comment: You should start with understanding what is `ssh-agent` for and how does it work before trying to suit it your twisted use case.

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: @Jakuje The error was about a missing pubkey and asked "Have you started ssh-agent?".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## What is `ssh-agent` for and how does it work?

The `ssh-agent` keeps your decrypted keys securely in memory and in your session. There is no reasonable and safe way to preserve the decrypted keys among reboots/re-logins.

## OK, how can I automate it?

### Automate `ssh-agent` startup

Add

```
[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

to your `~/.bashrc` or other startup script (`~/.zshrc`).

### Automate adding the keys

The keys can be automatically added upon the first usage, when you add

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

to your `~/.ssh/config`.

For more information on `~/.ssh/config` see `man ssh_config`.

Comment: So you're saying if I enable AddKeysToAgent, then whenever I type `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` it will add my key?

Comment: If the agent is running and your `ssh` supports this option, then yes.

Comment: Can you please clarify how I would automate starting the `ssh-agent` then?

Comment: Basically, as explained in the other answer. `[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && eval $(ssh-agent)`

Comment: Does that work with zsh?

Comment: Yes, but in that case, it is not `~/.bashrc`, but `~/.zshrc` or similar file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49566/discussion-between-timotree-and-jakuje).

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.10, I ended up with *two* instances of `ssh-agent`, as it appears to come preinstalled (?) - you can check with `ps -e | grep 'ssh'` to see if it's running. I only needed to add the the `AddKeysToAgent yes` setting to `.ssh/config` to make added keys persist between reboots.

Comment: I suggest redirecting the output to `/dev/null`, otherwise the `ssh-agent` will print the pid when login, which might cause failing using `rsync`. See https://serverfault.com/a/328404/576442. You can use `[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 11):

**Add this to `~/.bashrc`**

This means ssh-agent will be started automatically when you open another session no your terminal

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
 eval `ssh-agent -s`
fi
```

if you need a key to be added to the agent also add this

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
 eval `ssh-agent -s`
 ssh-add ~/.ssh/<your private ssh key>
fi
```

Comment: This was a good answer but doesn't explain what the command does.

Comment: How can we persist passphrase?

Comment: this is critical for AWS EC2 if custom keys are needed